# Add html from assets folder in between angular html

Tags: angular

I want to load the html from my asset folder in between my html file of angular.
For eg:
Suppose this is my product.html of product component and detailPara.html and BlockPara.html are in assets folder which I have to add in between the product.html:

```
<div class="productPage">
....
<div innerHTML="../assets/product/detailPara.html"></div>
....
<div innerHTML="../assets/product/BlockPara.html"></div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: cant you create a component calls DetailParaComponent, BlockParaComponent and call them inside the parent ?

Comment: Can you please explain more I am not understanding,I am new to angular also, I already have product component in whose product.html I want to add the detailPara.html and blockPara.html from assets folder, these are static data.

Comment: @RinkiMishra check my post below If you any doubt then comment me I will help you.

Comment: If you want the inner html. you have to use the DOMSanitizer or else you can't use it. You have to bypassSecurityTrustHtml.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, create a component with name `detailPara` check below command to create `detailPara`:

```
ng generate component detailPara
```

Or:

```
ng g c detailPara
```

Both are same after that paste your **`detailPara.html`** code to that `detailPara` component and same for `BlockPara.html` create component with below command:

```
ng generate component BlockPara
```

Or:

```
ng g c BlockPara
```

and paste BlockPara.html code to `BlockPara` component.

and finally use like this:

```
<div class="productPage">
  <app-detail-para></app-detail-para>  // check before pasting

  <app-block-para></app-block-para>    // check before pasting
</div>
```

---

## Second Way

Using JavaScript

```js
 document.getElementById('detailPara').innerHTML =
      '<object type="text/html" data="assets/detailPara.html" ></object>';

    document.getElementById('blockPara').innerHTML =
      '<object type="text/html" data="assets/BlockPara.html" ></object>';
```

```html
<div class="productPage">
  <div id="detailPara"></div>

  <div id="blockPara"></div>
</div>
```

Here you can [check Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ua3j4z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: I actually want both the detailPara.html and BlockPara.html to be in assets folder only, because I want the option to change it, without creating the component can I directly access it from asset folder and add it in my main html file

Comment: ok then give me sometime I will edit my post

Comment: Thankyou for the solution, I just have one more question can we make the h1 color as green as default in app.css rather than doing it in detailPara.html

Comment: No you can't do that

Answer (score 1):

you can use it Like this.

```
let path = 'assets/' + {fileName} + '.html';
this._httpClient.get(path, {responseType: "text"}).subscribe(
data => {
//now you have the file content in 'data'
this.content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data);
});
```

just inject the DOMSanitizer in the constructor and you are good to go!!

and then in your HTML file.

```
<div class="productPage">
....
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div>
....
```

Comment: But I cannot make the h2 colour of the html inside the assets folder default as green by writting it in product.scss?

Comment: I have another question if the .html is not present in asset how can i show another div without causing my code to error

Comment: you can just use ngIF* and remove the innerhtml div from HTML file